# How to repair out of index exception?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

```
private int numberofallmessages = 0;
        private int countMsg = 0;
        private List<string> seenids = new List<string>();

        private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
                OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client PopClient = new OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client();
                PopClient.Connect("mail", 110, false);
                PopClient.Authenticate("me", "mo",
                    OpenPop.Pop3.AuthenticationMethod.UsernameAndPassword);
                List<string> uids = PopClient.GetMessageUids();
                List<string> seenUids = new List<string>();
                int messageCount = 30;
                numberofallmessages = messageCount;
                allMessages = new List<OpenPop.Mime.Message>(messageCount);
                for (int i = messageCount - 1; i > -1; i--)
                {
                    if (backgroundWorker1.CancellationPending == true)
                    {
                        e.Cancel = true;
                        return;
                    }
                    string currentUidOnServer = uids[i];
                    if (!seenUids.Contains(currentUidOnServer))
                    {
                        allMessages.Add(PopClient.GetMessage(i));
                        SaveFullMessage(PopClient.GetMessage(i), i);
                        w = new StreamWriter(emailsIDSFile, true);
                        w.WriteLine((i + 1) + " = " + currentUidOnServer);
                        w.Close();
                        int nProgress = (messageCount - i + 1) * 100 / messageCount;
                        backgroundWorker1.ReportProgress(nProgress, PopClient.GetMessageCount().ToString() + "/" + i);
                    }
                }
                PopClient.Disconnect();
        }
```

The exception is on the line:

```
allMessages.Add(PopClient.GetMessage(i));
```

When the exception happen now the variable 'i' is 0
The variable allMessages List is 29
And the variable messageCount is 30

The messageNumber argument cannot have a value of zero or less. Valid messageNumber is in the range [1, messageCount]

Comment: Well the exception message seems fairly clear - it looks like `Pop3Client.GetMessage` takes a 1-based value, not a 0-based value. (It's in the documentation, too - http://hpop.sourceforge.net/documentation/OpenPop~OpenPop.Pop3.Pop3Client.GetMessage.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to description the valid messages start at 1 but you loop to 0:

```
            for (int i = messageCount - 1; i > -1; i--)
```

Should be:

```
            for (int i = messageCount; i > 0; i--)
```